# ZF2 - shared models between modules

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

In current state I've got two modules - main module, and admin panel module.
Main module is called "Kreator", admin -> "KreatorAdmin". All the models are located inside the Kreator module (Kreator/Model/UserTable.php etc.).

"KreatorAdmin" is almost empty, there is a configuration for it:

**KreatorAdmin/config/module.config.php**

```
<?php
return array(
  'controllers' => array(
    'invokables' => array(
      'KreatorAdmin\Controller\Admin' => 'KreatorAdmin\Controller\AdminController',
    ),
  ),


  'router' => array(
    'routes' => array(
      'zfcadmin' => array(
        'options' => array(
          'defaults' => array(
            'controller' => 'KreatorAdmin\Controller\Admin',
            'action'     => 'index',
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),

  'view_manager' => array(
    'template_path_stack' => array(
      __DIR__ . '/../view'
    ),
  ),
);
```

**KreatorAdmin/src/KreatorAdmin/AdminController.php**

```
<?php

namespace KreatorAdmin\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;


class AdminController extends AbstractActionController
{


  public function indexAction()
  {

    //$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Kreator\Model\UserTable');

    return new ViewModel();
  }
}
```

**KreatorAdmin/Module.php**

```
<?php
namespace KreatorAdmin;

class Module
{
    public function getConfig()
    {
        return include __DIR__ . '/config/module.config.php';
    }

    public function getAutoloaderConfig()
    {
        return array(
            'Zend\Loader\StandardAutoloader' => array(
                'namespaces' => array(
                    __NAMESPACE__ => __DIR__ . '/src/' . __NAMESPACE__,
                ),
            ),
        );
    }
}
```

Simply adding "use" statements in controller and navigating by namespaces results in error

> Argument 1 passed to KreatorAdmin\Controller\AdminController::__construct() must be an instance of Kreator\Model\UserTable, none given,

I also tried to play a bit with service manager as described here:
[ZF2 Models shared between Modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15083002/zf2-models-shared-between-modules) but no luck so far.

How am I supposed to access UserTable from KreatorAdmin/src/KreatorAdmin/AdminController.php ?

Cheers!

**update 1**
I've added getServiceConfig to Module.php

```
public function getServiceConfig()
{
  return [
    'factories' => [
      // 'Kreator\Model\UserTable' => function($sm) {
      //   $tableGateway = $sm->get('UserTableGateway');
      //   $table = new UserTable($tableGateway);
      //   return $table;
      // },
      // 'UserTableGateway' => function($sm) {
      //   $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
      //   $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
      //   $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new User());
      //   return new TableGateway('user', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
      // },

      'DbAdapter' => function (ServiceManager $sm) {
        $config = $sm->get('Config');
        return new Adapter($config['db']);
      },
      'UserTable' => function (ServiceManager $sm) {
        return new UserTable($sm->get('UserTableGateway'));
      },
      'UserTableGateway' => function (ServiceManager $sm) {
        $dbAdapter = $sm->get('DbAdapter');
        $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();

        $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new User());
        return new TableGateway('users', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);
      },
    ],
  ];
}
```

And updated controller

```
class AdminController extends AbstractActionController
{

  protected $userTable;

  public function indexAction()
  {

    $userTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Kreator\Model\UserTable');

    return new ViewModel();
  }
}
```

First error - using commented version:

> Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter

Second - using uncommented part:

> Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException: Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager::get was unable to fetch or create an instance for Kreator\Model\UserTable

**Solution**

If anyone wonder. Using above configuration there is a correct solution in **jobaer** answer. 
Using commented version, you have to remember to add

```
 'Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter' => 'Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterServiceFactory',
```

somewhere in config to service_manager.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be you messed up with ZF2 and ZF3 configuration. I am not sure but somewhere may be, you tried to create a factory of `AdminController` by passing an instance of `UserTable` to make it available inside `AdminController`'s action methods. And later **you are not passing that instance of `UserTable` into the `AdminController`'s constructor** while working with it further. The highlighted part from the previous line results in that error.

In **ZF2** you do not need to pass that `UserTable` instance in the controller's constructor for its availability. Just use the following one in any controller's action methods.

```
$userTable = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable');
```

If want to know how this process is done, please, refer to [this part of the tutorial](https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/database-and-models.html).

Comment: Hi, thanks for an answer. I've updated the question with full code.
Still can't get it to work tho. Any ideas?

Yes, there are use statements.

Comment: Just updated my answer. Use this `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('UserTable')` instead of `$this->getServiceLocator()->get('Kreator\Model\UserTable')` if you want to go with **uncommented** configuration. Let me know if that works.